# How to destroy a resource with terraform TF file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I create a terraform file that create AWS EC2 instance on AWS console then i create an AMI from that instance, know i want to destroy running instance and keep AMI with terraform language, what should i do?
Thanks you attentions

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
terraform destroy -target aws_instance.NAME
```

substitute your Terraformed EC2 instance's name